# links from within jquery tabs do not open other tabs

Tags: jquery, asp.net, tabs, hyperlink

Below is the code I'm using. Right now the tabs section works fine and it switched between tabs. The problem is I have a image in a div with a class called "showMem" at the bottom of every tab. That link is supposed to open up the last tab but its not working. The code I got for opening the tab is here [JQuery Docs](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Tabs#...select_a_tab_from_a_text_link_instead_of_clicking_a_tab_itself). Any idea? Thank you in advance.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

    var $tabs = $('#tabs').tabs(); // first tab selected

        $('.showMem').click(function() { // bind click event to link
            $tabs.tabs('select', 4); // switch to third tab
            return false;
                }).css({
                    cursor : 'pointer'
        });

        var $items = $('#tabs>ul>li');
        var $theImg = $('#tabs>ul>li>a>img');
        $items.click(function () {
            $items.removeClass('selected');
            $(this).addClass('selected');
            if ($items.index($(this)) == 0) { //Intro

                $items.removeClass('tab1Selected');
                $items.removeClass('tab2Selected');
                $items.removeClass('tab3Selected');
                $items.removeClass('tab4Selected');
                $items.removeClass('tab5Selected');
                $(this).addClass('tab1Selected');

            }
            else if ($items.index($(this)) == 1) { //About
                $items.removeClass('tab1Selected');
                $items.removeClass('tab2Selected');
                $items.removeClass('tab3Selected');
                $items.removeClass('tab4Selected');
                $items.removeClass('tab5Selected');
                $(this).addClass('tab2Selected');
            }
            else if ($items.index($(this)) == 2) { //Content
                $items.removeClass('tab1Selected');
                $items.removeClass('tab2Selected');
                $items.removeClass('tab3Selected');
                $items.removeClass('tab4Selected');
                $items.removeClass('tab5Selected');
                $(this).addClass('tab3Selected');
            }
            else if ($items.index($(this)) == 3) { //New Format
                $items.removeClass('tab1Selected');
                $items.removeClass('tab2Selected');
                $items.removeClass('tab3Selected');
                $items.removeClass('tab4Selected');
                $items.removeClass('tab5Selected');
                $(this).addClass('tab4Selected');
            }
            else if ($items.index($(this)) == 4) { //Membership
                $items.removeClass('tab1Selected');
                $items.removeClass('tab2Selected');
                $items.removeClass('tab3Selected');
                $items.removeClass('tab4Selected');
                $items.removeClass('tab5Selected');
                $(this).addClass('tab5Selected');
            }
            var index = $items.index($(this));
            $('#tabs>div').hide().eq(index).show();
        }).eq(0).click();

    });
</script> 



 <div id="tabs" class="ui-tabs">
    <img src="myimage.jpg" />
    <ul class="ui-tabs-nav">
        <li class="tab1"></li>
        <li class="tab2"></li>
        <li class="tab3"></li>
        <li class="tab4"></li>
        <li class="tab5"></li>
    </ul>

    <div id="tabs-1">
       <div class="showMem">image</a>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
        <p>blah blah blah</p>
        <div class="showMem">image</div>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-3">
        <p>Blah blah blah </p>
        <div class="showMem">image</div>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-4">
        <p>blach blah blach</p>
        <div class="showMem">image</div>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-5">
        <p>blah</p>
        <div class="showMem">image</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: "its not working" is not really enough for us to go on, especially with such a large block of code. Can you tells us about any errors that are displayed on the console, more information about the unintended actions that happen when you try to open the last tab, and/or consider posting a live demo (on your site or on [JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: It's fairly clear to me that the last tab is not opening for him as it is supposed.

Comment: You have serious problems on your HTML code. Please start by properly nesting and closing the HTML tags (DIVs, As, etc.). That may be the cause of your problems.

Comment: @george-cumming i haven't used JSFiddle but I just tried it out. I can't post a link to the live page. Hopefully this JSFiddle works better. I cleaned up a code a little more to only show the relevant things. http://jsfiddle.net/UjjYJ/1/ The problem I'm having is that I have 5 jquery tabs. I can click across the tabs just fine. But in each tab, I have a  link that when you click it, I want it to open the 5th tab. That link link doesn't work. I tried using the jquery docs and that didn't work. I tried making it a link back to my page with a querystring and that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this was a copy and paste error but I found a few things wrong. I pasted your code into [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L7PZP/1/), the markup was incorrect, you had some div nesting issues, the anchors were not present in the tabs so they didn't work

In some places you start off the image link as a div and finish as a closing 'a' tag.

```
<div class="showMem">image</a>
```

You also seem to have tried to implement your own tab system ontop of using the jquery 
UI tabs. This is unnecessary. I would recommend using [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/)  if you don't already. This showed instantly that your markup was wrong. After that it was very straight forward.

You can see that when you apply jquery ui tabs it adds a number of css classes to your elements. It's up to you to either include the standard css or write your own classes to make the behavior work. In the JsFiddle I simple tidied up your markup, added some anchors to the tabs to make them work, and added some css to make them look like tabs.

**EDIT**

I also edited your own jsfidde [here](http://jsfiddle.net/UjjYJ/3/) and added comments to the markup to show you where you were going wrong.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I simplified it and put it into JsFiddle. Hopefully this works. Also see the comments I added above. http://jsfiddle.net/UjjYJ/1/

Comment: What was wrong with my jsfiddle solution? It achieves what you asked. You click the link and it switches to the 5th tab. The problem was as stated that you broke the jquery ui tabs by implementing your own click functions on them and not using anchor tags in each tab to direct the code to display/hide the correct tag. I fixed that and got the link working. In case you missed the link here it is http://jsfiddle.net/L7PZP/1/

Comment: I didn't see that you fixed it in jsfiddle. That would have saved a lot of time knowing it was already fixed. Thank you very much. That's exactly how I was hoping it would work.

Comment: also, the reason I added all that other javasript code was to change the sprite that I use as the image on the tabs. Let me try your code out in my page and I'll let you know how it works out. Thanks again. I literally spent the better part of 2 work days on this one problem.

Comment: The problem I'm having now is that I want to change the background position of the currently selected tab. That's why I had all that other code. I'm guessing there must be an easier way to do that though.

Comment: I figured it out

    #tabs .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-selected div
    {
        background-position: 182px 0px;
    }